# Can't read body of request but can print it

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-functions, httprequest

I am pulling my hairs off. On `http` request, i can print a `body` object but can not access its content.

So i am sending a request like this from web:

```
  return fetch('https:xxxxxxx/xxxx', {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify(saleObject),
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'contentType':"application/json",
               'dataType':"json",
            }
          }).then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
          }).then(function(data) {
            return data.orderID;  
          });
        }
```

On my server (nodejs express Firebase ) , I am trying to read it in multiple ways :

```
exports.payPalIntent = functions.https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {
return cors(req, res, async () => {
 
   console.log("req.body",req.body);  //this print AN OBJECT, A REAL OBJECT NOT A STRING
   console.log("req address",req.body.address); //=undefined, there is address property inside which

   return res.send(200);
 });
```

So, the first one print this :

```
req.body {"address":{"city":"some city","zip":"345334","area":"USA","street":"Hai 13", ........
```

The second says `Cannot read property 'address' of undefined`

**Of course, i tried also** `JSON.stringify(req.body)` , which print a string object that i can't access.

How do you access this object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` turns a JavaScript object into a JSON string. You already have a JSON string and you want to covert it to a JavaScript object, so use the reverse: `JSON.parse(req.body)`. Then you should be able to access the properties using the dot operator.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason , i have read tones of examples, nobody parse it back. it just works for them with req.body , I have no idea how.

Comment: @phamng I think it's because you have this middleware-like function call `return res.json()` which stringifies the response. Remove that, and you shouldn't have to parse the response.